# What variance rules am I getting wrong?

Tags: probability

$\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}$It is just a general question I could not get my mind around.

Assume that $E[X]= 20$ and $\var[X]= 5$, then$$
E[1.2X]= 1.2·E[X]= 1.2×20= 24= 20 + 4 = E[X] + E[0.2X],\\
\var[1.2X]= 1.44·\var[X]= 1.44×5= 7.2.
$$
For$$
\var[1.2X]= \var[X + 0.2X]= \var[X] + \mathord{??} = \var[0.2x] \text{ or } \var[\sqrt{0.44}X],$$
how do I split up the variance here if I want to write it as $\var[X] + \var[aX]$?

Comment: thanks everyone! I know what i was trying to do is pretty much useless, I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If the variance of $A, B$ are $\sigma^2_A, \sigma^2_B$ then 
$Var(A+B) = \sigma^2_A + \sigma^2_B  + 2\text{cov} (A,B) =  \sigma^2_A + \sigma^2_B  + 2\sigma_A\sigma_B\rho_{A,B}$

If this reminds you of the law of cosines, it should.

In your case $X,0.2X$ are perfectly correlated, and $\rho = 1$

$$Var(X+0.2X) = Var(X) + Var(0.2X) + 2\sqrt{Var(X)Var(0.2X)}\\
5 + (0.04)(5) + 2\sqrt {(0.04)25} = (1.44)(5)$$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that:

$$\operatorname{Var}[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$$

Using the linearity of expectation, we derive:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\operatorname{Var}[X+Y]
&=& E[(X+Y)^2] - E[X+Y]^2 \\
&=& E[X^2] + 2E[XY] + E[Y^2] - E[X]^2 - 2E[X]E[Y] - E[Y]^2 \\
&=& \operatorname{Var}[X] + \operatorname{Var}[Y] + 2\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)
\end{array}$$

where $\operatorname{cov}$ denotes covariance.

If $Y = aX$, we obtain:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\operatorname{Var}[X+aX]
&=& \operatorname{Var}[X] + \operatorname{Var}[aX] + 2\operatorname{cov}(X,aX) \\
&=& \operatorname{Var}[X] + a^2 \operatorname{Var}[X] + 2a\operatorname{cov}(X,X) \\
&=& \operatorname{Var}[X] + a^2 \operatorname{Var}[X] + 2a\operatorname{Var}[X] \\
&=& (1+a)^2\operatorname{Var}[X]
\end{array}$$

which is not very helpful in my opinion. The formula you're seeking is the second last line.

Answer (score 1):

> how do i split up the variance here if i want to write it as $Var[X]+Var[aX]$
>   ?

$\begin{split}\mathsf {Var}(1.2X) &=1.2^2\mathsf{Var}(X) &~&=(1+0.2)^2\mathsf{Var}(X) \\ &=\mathsf {Var}(X)+(1.2^2-1)\mathsf{Var}(X) &&=\mathsf{Var}(X)+0.4\mathsf{Var}(X)+0.2^2\mathsf{Var}(X) \\ &=\mathsf {Var}(X)+\mathsf{Var}(X\sqrt{1.2^2-1})&&=\mathsf{Var}(X)+\mathsf{Var}(X\sqrt{0.4})+\mathsf{Var}(0.2X)\\&=\mathsf {Var}(X)+\mathsf{Var}(X\sqrt{0.44})\end{split}$

Better question: Why would you want to?   Variance is *not* linear .

Answer (score 0):

The rule $$\text{Var}(X+Y) = \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var} (Y)$$
is only valid if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. $X$ and $aX$ are never independent (this should be intuitively clear - if you know $X$ then you know $aX$) except in the case where $\text{Var}(X) = 0$, i.e. when $X$ is a point distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [basic property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) of the variance: $\text{Var}[aX]=a^2\text{Var}[X]$.

Hence:

$$\begin{align}\text{Var}[(1+a)X]&=(1+a)^2\text{Var}[X]=\\
&=\text{Var}[X]+(2a+a^2)\text{Var}[X]=\\
&=\text{Var}[X]+\text{Var}[\sqrt{2a+a^2}X].\end{align}$$
Note: Plug $a=0.2$ to get your answer.